# sha512 hashed result in C is different with other languages (php, python)

Tags: php, c, sha512

This is my first time to write code with C. I have a problem with sha512. The result is not same with other languages (php, python).

My target is use sha512 to encrypt the string loop more times. But first and second time is same with python or php, but start from third, it was different.

Result image:
[image]

Run on Linux.

Here is my code:

C

`$ gcc test.c -lcrypto -o test`

`$ ./test`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

char *hash_sha512(char *data) {
  SHA512_CTX ctx;
  char *md = malloc(sizeof(char)*(SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH+1));
  SHA512_Init(&ctx);
  SHA512_Update(&ctx, data, strlen(data));
  SHA512_Final(md, &ctx);
  md[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = '\0';

  return md;
}

int main(void) {

  char *str = hash_sha512("123456");
  FILE *fp;
  int count = 10;

  fp = fopen("/tmp/c.txt", "w+");
  do {
    fputs(str, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    str = hash_sha512(str);
  } while (--count);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$password='123456';
$hash = hash('sha512', $password, TRUE);
$i = 10;
do {
  file_put_contents('/tmp/php.txt',$hash . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
  $hash = hash('sha512', $hash, TRUE);
} while (--$i);
```

Python

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import hashlib
password='123456'
count = 10
f = open('/tmp/python.txt','a')
pass_hash = hashlib.sha512(password).digest()
for _ in range(count):
    f.write(pass_hash)
    pass_hash = hashlib.sha512(pass_hash).digest()
f.close()
```

Comment: Fyi, a sha digest isn't text; its *bytes*. Slamming a `'\0'` on the end doesn't magically change it to a zero-terminated string. I can guarantee you that digest will, at some point, have a zero-octet embedded. As soon as that happens, your C algorithm falls on the floor.

Comment: @Everright Chen you probably need to convert the hash in hex string or base64 string to be easier to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing apples to apples, and in the process also not computing your digest correctly for your C code. The byte stream emitted from a sha512 digest is not a C-string, and putting a zero-char on the end doesn't magically make it one. For example, the first digest looks like this (in hex):

```
ba 32 53 87 6a ed 6b c2 2d 4a 6f f5 3d 84 06 c6 
ad 86 41 95 ed 14 4a b5 c8 76 21 b6 c2 33 b5 48 
ba ea e6 95 6d f3 46 ec 8c 17 f5 ea 10 f3 5e e3 
cb c5 14 79 7e d7 dd d3 14 54 64 e2 a0 ba b4 13
```

The second digest is:

```
73 14 8c 26 3f fc 49 86 34 cc 1e be bd 67 51 69 
97 01 11 69 a3 7e 28 11 ed 51 d5 2c 82 d4 d5 72 
af 32 c2 31 13 9f 1d 0f d7 af e2 9e 44 1d 44 ae 
fa 29 c1 85 5e c6 52 07 63 92 72 11 0d 19 56 74
```

and the third, this:

```
a5 b2 65 20 84 63 58 8b 56 c1 08 4c 37 03 c4 a1 
a9 0c 71 05 89 cb 09 fc 22 07 85 8f 64 3b b1 72 
8b 3e f3 f3 06 2c 84 72 f8 3a c6 1f f9 47 87 b8 
b8 00 3d 73 0b 29 a3 7b 88 a9 e3 14 ee 19 06 f7
```

Do you see it? Look at the last set of octets. Last row, second byte.

```
b8 00 3d 73 0b 29 a3 7b 88 a9 e3 14 ee 19 06 f7 
   ^^
```

Since your digest source length is erroneously based on a C string length, that is where it is cut off. The remaining bytes are ignored and your digest chain is forever-more wrong.

Apart from that, your code leaks memory like a sieve leaks rainwater. Probably not a big deal for 640 bytes and 10 iterations, but move this to a million iterations and it starts adding up. Put it in a mission-critical piece of software and it is entirely unacceptable. Consider this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void hash_sha512(unsigned char const *src, size_t len, unsigned char *dst)
{
    SHA512_CTX ctx;
    SHA512_Init(&ctx);
    SHA512_Update(&ctx, src, len);
    SHA512_Final(dst, &ctx);
}

int main(void)
{
    char pwd[] = "123456"
    unsigned char digest[2][SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {{0}};
    hash_sha512((unsigned char*)pwd, strlen(pwd), digest[0]);

    unsigned int count=1;
    for (; count<10; ++count)
    {
        hash_sha512(digest[(count-1)%2], SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH, digest[count%2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This fixes the problem described earlier, and the final digest will be in `digest[(count-1)%2]`.I leave it to you to integrate your file IO. Below is the first 10 iterations using an initial password of `"123456"` for your reference. I suggest you use `hexdump` to make sure things are going according to plan.

**Ten Iterations**

```
ba 32 53 87 6a ed 6b c2 2d 4a 6f f5 3d 84 06 c6 
ad 86 41 95 ed 14 4a b5 c8 76 21 b6 c2 33 b5 48 
ba ea e6 95 6d f3 46 ec 8c 17 f5 ea 10 f3 5e e3 
cb c5 14 79 7e d7 dd d3 14 54 64 e2 a0 ba b4 13 

73 14 8c 26 3f fc 49 86 34 cc 1e be bd 67 51 69 
97 01 11 69 a3 7e 28 11 ed 51 d5 2c 82 d4 d5 72 
af 32 c2 31 13 9f 1d 0f d7 af e2 9e 44 1d 44 ae 
fa 29 c1 85 5e c6 52 07 63 92 72 11 0d 19 56 74 

a5 b2 65 20 84 63 58 8b 56 c1 08 4c 37 03 c4 a1 
a9 0c 71 05 89 cb 09 fc 22 07 85 8f 64 3b b1 72 
8b 3e f3 f3 06 2c 84 72 f8 3a c6 1f f9 47 87 b8 
b8 00 3d 73 0b 29 a3 7b 88 a9 e3 14 ee 19 06 f7 

75 15 b6 cb ef 3e 0b 4a 35 e3 58 b9 8b bb a3 2d 
a0 bd 1e c8 9d 32 23 7c 09 ae c0 a7 f7 4e 70 35 
c8 34 dd 2a ac 8d e4 e9 d1 e8 b5 7a 80 d8 80 db 
07 7c 28 18 e8 30 40 aa 06 85 a5 2a 63 41 c6 b7 

4d 25 d3 24 5e 22 b1 e4 e4 3f 1e a4 4e a3 eb e4 
89 ab e3 c2 63 56 01 17 ea 1f 85 58 d4 da d2 63 
6d 9c 2f 74 39 b6 87 85 2c 1c 27 f8 a8 9d 2a cf 
ee 64 1c d9 28 5d 88 e5 c7 8b 9f 6e 1e c8 dd 99 

17 e2 7f 2f fd a7 c3 b7 41 73 b9 2d e7 61 6e 77 
72 79 41 16 14 90 01 db 6f 66 3b e6 12 94 22 06 
a9 91 14 55 ab 7f 3a 34 eb 12 b3 a9 78 69 6a 23 
8e 82 13 46 1e ed b4 33 e8 74 f8 15 15 a3 19 57 

c1 60 9e c9 c4 82 4f 1c 71 a7 e2 7c 6e fc d9 5b 
63 4f 27 25 ec fe d2 58 d6 77 61 8f 93 a1 a4 1e 
f0 b7 8a 24 36 91 40 9b 5f dd c3 b5 b9 e1 c6 97 
24 66 89 b0 79 c2 84 05 8e 4f 43 4b 5a bb 53 e6 

7b f9 4c 45 be 2f 29 68 80 36 79 b7 1a 79 36 a3 
7e 8b 9f 6e a0 80 3a 9e 5c bc 27 39 bd 2e 6e 9f 
5a b2 8c b9 7f 43 9f b2 c4 72 41 99 f7 65 71 26 
b7 b8 06 24 a8 34 ea 69 e4 05 ab 55 a7 a8 32 c2 

1a 28 09 ee c5 a4 e5 86 98 0f 52 a1 fd ff a6 14 
0f 3f 8b 14 85 34 bd a6 bd 45 54 2e 4c 2b da 62 
d0 7c 98 38 5c 98 cd 76 df 18 ca 36 16 f2 be 8e 
6c ed 76 e8 28 39 e6 38 d7 41 a4 9e 31 6d f0 ab 

ce 0c 0f 2e 89 e5 1d c3 58 88 a3 1f a6 7c 18 74 
1a 20 d3 84 43 9c 3a e8 4b d9 f1 fe 2e a1 67 0b 
62 62 2d dc 02 eb 82 cd 90 b2 0f 8f e2 fe f5 43 
7a ad 0c b1 62 d7 e9 45 3f be 14 53 2e b6 d0 68
```

Comment: @Giorgi the formal parameter type is `unsigned char const*`. I could have just passed it and lived with the warning; momentary lapse of a C++ engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @WhozCraig.

Here is my final code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main(void) {
  char pwd[] = "123456";
  unsigned char digest[2][SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {{0}};
  SHA512((unsigned char*)pwd, strlen(pwd), digest[0]);

  unsigned int count = 1;
  for (; count<10; ++count) {
    SHA512(digest[(count-1)%2], SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH, digest[count%2]);
  }

  unsigned char result[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1];
  unsigned int i = 0;
  for(; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    sprintf(&result[i*2], "%02x", digest[(count-1)%2][i]);
  }
  printf("The result is %s.\n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: added +1 to final string length to account for final nulllchar terminator.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks. 
In for loop, if i want to append pwd "123456" to hashed result "digest[(count-1)%2]" for the next encrypt string like 
"digest[(count-1)%2]" join "pwd"
How should i do it, have any idea?